# Автодополнение js в VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Как настроить автодополнение таким образом, чтобы добавлялось не только имя функции, но и скобки после него?

К примеру после выбора функции хотелось бы получать условный alert();, а не просто само alert

При этом сниппеты для тех же циклов и function работают прекрасно

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то его надо записать в settings.json со значением true. Если так, то не помогает(

Comment: хмм, наверное да, но я просто открыл настройки, вставил это туда и кликнул галочку, если не поможет - попробуй перезагрузиться с отключенными плагинами.

Comment: такс, ну в файлах js вроде работает, в html в теге script еще бы как-то сделать)